# What is the probability that a coin is a loaded coin?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, randomness

If you randomly pick a coin from a box that contains $90\%$ fair coins and $10\%$ loaded coins, (a loaded coin gives heads $90\%$ of the time), toss it $5$ times and get all heads. What is the probability that this is a loaded coin?

$$n = 5, x = 5, p = 0.1(0.9)^5$$

Where $n$  is the number of flips, $x$ is number of heads, and  $p$ is the probability of getting heads.
so
$$( 0.1 (0.9)^5 ) + (0.9 (0.5)^5) = 0.087$$

Can anyone see if the answer I provided is correct or not !

Comment: It looks like you asked this question before and we told you what the right formula is. It looks like the parentheses are messed up .It might be right if the second multiplication sign was a plus sign.  There should not be a term involving 0.9 raised to the 10th power which it seems you have.

Comment: This is a duplicate of his earlier question but not of Checking whether a coin is fair. I vote to leave it open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

Try using these formula.

From Bayes Theorem

$$P(\text{loaded }| 5\text{ heads}) = P(5\text{ heads|loaded}) \frac{P(\text{loaded})}{P(\text{5 heads)}}$$
where by law of total probability:
$$P(5 \text{ heads}) =P(5\text{ heads|loaded}) P(\text{loaded})+ P(5\text{ heads|fair}) P(\text{fair})$$

Comment: That is what we suggested in the previous post. I gave you +1 anyway.

Comment: I made an edit to my question see if now my answer is correct, then I will approve your posted answer :)

Comment: You have the formula right now.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I had the formula before as well, but I wasn't sure as where to put my values in the formula, that's why I asked if the way I put my values are now Okay ?

Comment: You might want to state what do you think  the values for $P(\text{fair})$, $P(5 \text{ heads}|\text{fair})$, $P(\text{loaded})$, $P(5 \text{ heads}|\text{loaded})$ are explicitly before you apply the formula.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh +1 your comment, so here $$P(fair) = 0.9, P(5 heads|fair) = 0.9^5, P(loaded) = 0.1, P(5 heads|loaded) = 0.9^5 $$ and see my question I applied there as well, now do you think my final result is right ?

Comment: $P(5 \text{ heads}|\text{fair})$  is not quite right. Try again? Also, the quantity of interest would be $P(\text{loaded} | 5 \text{ heads})$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh oh yeah you are right, I just changed it $$0.5^5$$. check now

Comment: I can see that you mean $0.5^5$. Now you have all the ingredient, you  just have to sustitute them to get the desired quantity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66806/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-hazmat).